# Paros Proxy asking for HTTP authentication while monitoring an open site

Tags: proxy

I am using Paros proxy for checking and monitoring my site. The site doesn't have any HTTP based authentication but while running through paros proxy it is saying "A username and password are being requested by http://XYZ.com. The site says: "XDB" " I've tried several different paros settings and sites but it is showing me the same thing. It seems paros has some default HTTP auth credentials. I've also tried entering login creds in the config.xml but it didn't worked out. Any help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paros hasnt been updated for many years.

Try using OWASP ZAP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

Its a fork of Paros but has much more functionality and is being very actively maintained.

Simon (ZAP Project lead)